# Twitter Account Activity API - How to subscribe webhooks to events?

Tags: api, go, twitter, webhooks, subscription

I am developing a Twitter bot using golang. I have been following the instructions written [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/creating-a-twitter-bot-from-scratch-with-golang-e1f37a66741/)

In order to make my webhook listen (subscribe) to the activity of a Twitter account (the bot), I have to subscribe my webhook to events. The guideline is in [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/customer-engagement-application-playbook)

This is where I am stuck. I have managed to register my webhook but I keep failing to subscribe it to events.

Here is the code I run:

```
func main() {
    //Load env
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
        log.Println("Error loading .env file")
    }


    subscribeWebhook()
}

func CreateClient() *http.Client {
    //Create oauth client with consumer keys and access token
    config := oauth1.NewConfig(os.Getenv("CONSUMER_KEY"), os.Getenv("CONSUMER_SECRET"))
    token := oauth1.NewToken(os.Getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY"), os.Getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"))

    return config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)
}

func subscribeWebhook() {
    log.Println("Subscribing webapp...")
    client := CreateClient()
    path := "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/all/" + os.Getenv("WEBHOOK_ENV") + "/subscriptions.json"
    resp, err := client.PostForm(path, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    //If response code is 204 it was successful
    if resp.StatusCode == 204 {
        log.Println("Subscribed successfully")
    } else if resp.StatusCode != 204 {
        log.Println("Could not subscribe the webhook. Response below:")
        log.Println(string(body))
    }
}
```

And this is the response I get:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 348,
            "message": "Client application is not permitted to access this user's webhook subscriptions."
        }
    ]
}
```

Please, anyone help me figure this out. Thank you folks.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

Turns out, on the app setting in the developer portal you have to give full permission (Read, Write, and Direct Messages) to you app. Then, regenerate your keys and tokes. Lastly update your env variables with the new keys and tokens.